# google font only ie9 and the rest?

Tags: css, fonts, conditional-statements, google-font-api

I am using Google Fonts to load two fonts.  Since they look absolutely horrible in anything below ie9 I want to disregard them.  Here is what I am thinking :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html lang="en-US"><!--<![endif]-->
```

then in my css I could use something like this :

```
h1{
font: normal 33px/50px 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
```

}

```
.ie8 h1{
font: normal 33px/50px 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
```

}

That takes care of it trying to use Open Sans.  What about loading the actual stylesheet.  Would something like this be fine?

```
<!--[if !(lte IE 8) ]>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

This would prevent ie8 and under from even loading the css and prevent wasted download - correct? Is this the correct syntax?

Anyone recommend a better way?  I have tried loading all the fonts separate and they still do not work right in ie8 and 7 so that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use something like this to exclude IE8 and lower:

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kite+One|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

The first one only loads the font for IE9 and above. The second one loads it for all non-IE browsers.

Alternatively, you could load the fonts with JavaScript.

Comment: cool... did't think about going to two statement route - thanks.